# How is the q(z) function added at the end of this Bayesian formula?

Tags: probability, bayesian, density-function

At the bottom of this Bayesian formula why is a q(z) is brought into numerator and denominator positions?

Is this within the rules of Algebra? Could anything be placed in the numerator and denominator?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiplication by $1=\frac{q(z)}{q(z)}$ is an identity. The rest is just re-arranging.

$$\begin{align}
p(y | \theta) &= \frac{p(y|z, \theta)p(z|\theta)}{p(z|y, \theta)} \\
&= p(y|z, \theta)p(z|\theta) \cdot \frac{1}{p(z|y, \theta)}  \\
&= p(y|z, \theta)p(z|\theta) \cdot \frac{1}{p(z|y, \theta)} \cdot 1 \\
&= p(y|z, \theta)p(z|\theta) \cdot \frac{1}{p(z|y, \theta)} \cdot \frac{q(z)}{q(z)} \\
&= \frac{p(y|z, \theta)p(z|\theta)}{q(z)} \cdot \frac{q(z)}{p(z|y, \theta)}
\end{align}$$

Presumably, there's some reason that $q(z) \neq 0~ \forall z$.